# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on 3D Printing breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         12
Users destroyed                                  59          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           218        367
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                2         22
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         47        183
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               43        130
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               190        493
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               18        543
Tags merged                                       1          0
Questions reopened                                6          0
Questions protected                               1         10
Questions migrated                                1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0        501
Questions closed                                 23         80
Question flags handled⁴                          76        425
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                  27         18
Posts locked                                      1         86
Posts deleted⁵                                  137        229
Posts bumped                                      0        190
Comments undeleted                               19          0
Comments flagged                                 63        262
Comments deleted⁶                               387        534
Comment flags handled                           257         68
Answers flagged                                   5        488
Answer flags handled                            252        241
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of 3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Applause on being our second 101-point diamond poking through! Happy new year to you and your colleagues and a big thanks for hosting us!